# How to set string into TextInputEditText with inputType — number

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I have a field — TextInputEditText with inputType number. When user input smth into field, big numbers should divide by empty space. But when I use setText method for this like this:

`inputEditText.setText("1 000")`

I get error — `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1 000"`

My XML code for field:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/textInputContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/rightGuideline"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/leftGuideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/abonementField"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_abonement_field"
            android:digits="0123456789"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:textColor="#9A000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:errorTextColor="@color/lightRed"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            tools:text="@string/visit_amount_error_first_part" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bottomErrorMessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/red"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:text="@string/visit_amount_error_first_part" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/counter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/subtitle_text_color"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            tools:text="0/100" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

My spacer code:

```
abonementField
    .afterTextChangeEvents()
    .distinctUntilChanged { it -> it.toString() }
    .subscribe {
        val inputText = abonementField.text.toString().replace(" ", "")

        when (item.fieldType) {
            AbonementFieldType.VISIT_COST -> {

                val formattedText = when (inputText.length) {
                    ONE_DIGIT, TWO_DIGIT, THREE_DIGIT -> inputText
                    FOUR_DIGIT -> {
                        StringBuilder()
                            .append(inputText.take(ONE_DIGIT))
                            .append(EMPTY_SPACE)
                            .append(inputText.drop(ONE_DIGIT))
                    }

                    FIFTH_DIGIT -> {
                        StringBuilder()
                            .append(inputText.take(TWO_DIGIT))
                            .append(EMPTY_SPACE)
                            .append(inputText.drop(TWO_DIGIT))
                    }

                    SIXTH_DIGIT -> inputText.chunked(THREE_DIGIT).joinToString(" ")
                    SEVENTH_DIGIT -> {
                        val digitTail = inputText.drop(ONE_DIGIT)
                            .chunked(THREE_DIGIT).joinToString(" ")
                        StringBuilder()
                            .append(inputText.take(ONE_DIGIT))
                            .append(EMPTY_SPACE)
                            .append(digitTail)
                    }

                    EIGHT_DIGIT -> {
                        val digitTail = inputText.drop(ONE_DIGIT)
                            .chunked(THREE_DIGIT).joinToString(" ")
                        StringBuilder()
                            .append(inputText.take(TWO_DIGIT))
                            .append(EMPTY_SPACE)
                            .append(digitTail)
                    }

                    else -> ""
                }

                if (formattedText.isNotBlank()) {
                    if (formattedText.toString().toInt() > 0) {
                        abonementField.setText(formattedText)
                    } else if (formattedText.toString().toInt() == 0) {
                        val allowSingleZero =
                            formattedText.toString().replaceAfter("0", "")
                        abonementField.setText(allowSingleZero)
                    }
                }

                if (inputText.length >= EIGHT_DIGIT && inputText.toInt() > MAX_COST_OF_VISIT) {
                    abonementField.setText(inputText.take(EIGHT_DIGIT))
                    showFieldError()
                } else if (inputText.isNotBlank()) {
                    showFieldLabel()
                }
            }
```

How to fix this? And it's possible?

I try to use inputType string, but I need to show only digits to user

Answer (score 0):

I think DecimalFormat can help you, using space as the grouping separator:

```
val formatPattern = "# ### ### ###.##"
val formatSymbols = DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale("ru", "RU"))
formatSymbols.setGroupingSeparator = ' ' // use space as separator
val wantedFormat = DecimalFormat(formatPattern, formatSymbols)
val yourNumberFormatted = wantedFormat.format(yourNumber)
```